# Force javascript to reevaluate on signals?

Tags: qt, javascript, qobject, qt-signals

So I have the following case:

QML file:

```
import "Script.js" as MyScript

SomeItem{
    source: MyScript.getSource
}
```

JavaScript file ( Script.js ) :

```
function getSource(){
    return _SomeQtObject.getFromQtObjectSource();
}
```

Let's say I have some signals in the SomeQtObject based on which getSource should reevaluate. How do I bind those signals to the javaScript getSource function so that it reevaluates every time those signals are emitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force to reevaluate the result of javascript function automaticaly.

You have to create the slot which is connected to the apropriate signal of `_SomeQtObject`. In this slot you can reevaluate `getSource()` and assign it ro `source`.